# Obtener el mes a partir de una columna de la forma YYYY/MM/DD en pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

Tengo un `DataFrame` con 2 columnas, "`released`" y "`value`".
De la columna "`released`", que esta en forma de fecha YYYY-MM-DD, quiero obtener simplemente el mes (en números) para después poder usarlo junto a los datos de la columna "`value`" y hacer un gráfico.

Que debo escribir? ya sea manipulando los strings o usando datetime.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo de esta forma:

```
raw_data = {'value': [20, 19, 22, 21],
            'released': ['01-02-1996', '08-05-1997', '04-28-1996', '12-16-1995']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df['mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['released']).month

   value    released  mes
0     20  01-02-1996    1
1     19  08-05-1997    8
2     22  04-28-1996    4
3     21  12-16-1995   12
```